# Bulk insert class object in sqllite database in node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I have the following class called Label:

```
class Label{
    constructor(imageid, plotid, camera, date, x, y, w, h, id, hash){
      this.imageid = imageid;
      this.plotid = plotid;
      this.camera = camera;
      this.date = date;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.w = w;
      this.h = h;
      this.id = id;
      this.hash = hash
    }
  }
```

I have a list of these class objects called `labels` that I want to insert, or rather bulk insert into my sqllite database, which looks like the following:

[image: Label table in db]

I tried to insert this array of class objects with:

```
function addRowsToDb(){
    console.log("Adding rows to the db")
    db = new sqlite3.Database('./annotator.db');
    db.serialize(function() {

        var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO Label(ImageID, PlotID, Camera, Date, x, y, w, h, LabelHash) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        labels.forEach((label) => {
            stmt.run(label.imageid, label.plotid, label.camera, label.date, label.x, label.y, label.w, label.h, label.hash);
        })
        stmt.finalize();
    });
    db.close();
}
```

Which gave me the following errors in the console:

> Uncaught Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: Label.ImageID
>
> Uncaught Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: Label.LabelHash

Could someone explain to me how to do this properly and how to do this with bulk data, so not the forEach with the labels array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is pretty straight forward - you try to insert `NULL` values into non-nullable db columns (`Label.ImageID` and `Label.LabelHash`).

How to solve this depends on what makes the most sense for your app:

- remove the `NOT NULL` constraint on those columns
- skip the labels that don't have `ImageID` and `LabelHash` set
- provide a default value (empty string for example) for the `ImageID` and `LabelHash` cols

Comment: That was it, pretty stupid of me not to see that while debugging. Do you know any way though to do a bulk insert?